# Generating java class from proto-buf (not using protobuf-lite)

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I had success generating protobuf code to java using `java-lite`, problem is that I need plain 'java'

Project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.13"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maartin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    sourceSets.main.java.filter.exclude 'META-INF/**/*'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/**/*'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-alpha02"

    implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.13.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/main/proto'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0'
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code on top is working flawlessly, but generates javalite version. How can I generate simple java?

What I tried:

Project level: `stays the same`

Module level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.13"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maartin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties"
        pickFirst "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"

        exclude 'META-INF/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'


        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/transport/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/codec-http2/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/codec-http2/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/codec-http2/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/buffer/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/handler/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/common/native-image.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/transport/reflection-config.json'
        exclude 'META-INF/native-image/io.netty/codec-http/native-image.properties'

        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }

    sourceSets.main.java.filter.exclude 'META-INF/**/*'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/**/*'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.3'
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-alpha02"

    implementation group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.12.0'
    implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-all', version: '1.29.0'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
            srcDir 'src/main/proto'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0'
    }

    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.29.0'
        }
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {
                outputSubDir = 'java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With new approach - I do not run into errors, but `build/generated/source/proto` has only debug folder (java files are not generated)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the following part is problematic.

```
grpc {
    outputSubDir = 'java'
}
```

It overrides the output directory name for the `grpc` plugin to `java`. However, 'java' directory is the default directory for the `java` builtin. The consequence of this is that the generated gRPC service code overwrites the generated Java message code. Can you try changing it to something else or just leave it for default?

Comment: I left grpc { } blank. It now generates build/generated/source/proto/debug/grpc folder only, which is empty.

Comment: You should be able to see two directories: build/generated/source/proto/debug/grpc and build/generated/source/proto/debug/java. The former contains contains the generated gRPC code (only if you have defined RPC services in your proto, otherwise, it will be empty) and the latter contains the generated code for protobuf messages.

Comment: For some reason, I've only one folder in build/generated/source/proto/debug and it's grpc - empty as it should be. What configuration am I missing here?

Comment: What else did you change compared to the build for javalite? I saw you added gRPC. Where do you put your proto files?